# how can i get all the residential nodes in a specific region in overpass turbo?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm new to osm queries and I explore it using overpass turbo so I'm trying  that gets a specific way with a predefine id the code looks like this if anyone would like to test

```
[bbox:40.73112,-73.89061,40.73391,-73.88807];
// gather results
(
  way(5703091);
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

when I did explore the XML file in the data view I saw that this way contain all of these nodes that make the way

```
  <way id="5703091">
    <nd ref="42839143"/>
    <nd ref="8219742075"/>
    <nd ref="42807002"/>
    <nd ref="42839146"/>
    <nd ref="42839155"/>
    <nd ref="42839161"/>
    <nd ref="42839168"/>
    <nd ref="2875111804"/>
    <nd ref="42839172"/>
```

so is there a way to show these nodes in the map view without assign each one individually with the query
i try to use node(5703091); but office didn't work since it is a way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in overpass turbo

```
way(5703091)->.Way;
node(w.Way);
out center;
.Way out geom;
```